# Create nested REST call with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, rest, nested

I have searched Stack Overflow and while I have found some answers none of them seem to address the issue I am struggling with.

I an trying to code for the REST call parameters shown below:

```
{
    "asset": [
        "Images",
            "BsnName"
  ],
  "cntToken": "840009561449",
  "language": "us-en",
  "idToken": "myToken"
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how to set this up?

I had thought the below would work but I get the error:

> Expected ':' in dictionary literal

```
let params: NSMutableDictionary? = [
    "asset": "asset",
        [
            "Images": "Images",
            "BsnName": "BsnName"
        ],
    "cntToken": "840009561449",
    "language": "us-en",
    "idToken": "myToken"
];
```

Comment: Is the value of `asset` supposed to be an array (according to the JSON), or a dictionary (according to the code)?

Comment: The error you are getting is for the bit `"asset": "asset", [...]` It should be just `"asset":  [...]`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, there's rarely a reason to use the old Obj-C type `NSMutableDictionary` -- you can use the Swift `Dictionary` type instead. You can let the compiler do the type inference for you, or you can annotate it explicitly as I've done below.

In your translation of the JSON, you've added an extra "asset" instead of just using the internal `Array` as the value for the "asset" key. Also, the internal value should be an `Array` and not another `Dictionary`

```
let params: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "asset": 
        ["Images", "BsnName"],
    "cntToken": "840009561449",
    "language": "us-en",
    "idToken": "myToken"
]
```

Also, in Swift it's usually not idiomatic to end statements with a `;`

Comment: Actually *In Swift, there's **no** reason...* 

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually the asset is one of the parameters for the REST call.

Comment: @DavidS Right -- I've matched what you have in the JSON. In your Swift, the code was incorrect. If this answers the question, please mark it as correct using the green checkmark. If not, please clarify what the issue is.